# Load an image from an json object onto a html webpage

Tags: html, json, image, object

I'm new to json so as a general question, is there a way to put an image file (for example; {"image": "image.jpg"}) that displays an image onto an html web page. If so, how would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question would make more sense if you provided some context.

Comment: @eltonkamami It's just a general question, I'm asking how to load an image onto a web page from a json file by putting the file name into an object.

Comment: Instead of the file name, you can store the file path as the value in json like suppose you have a json named "details":

    details :{
       image : "/src/images/image.jpg"
    }

Now in your html, you can read this JSON use it in img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 - you store images on your server

## 2 - On your server you have json available to your client via a webserver.

## 3 - content of json will look like:

{title_image : "/high/titleimage.png"}

## 3 - in your client you parse the json file. For example with jQuery you would do something like:

```
var url = "myawesomeapi.com";

$.get(url)
        .done(function( data ) {
            
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            jQuery("#my_image").attr("src", data.title_image) 
                                
        });
```